# android camera app

Tags: android

I am trying to build a camera app.
in the first activity user can see the camera preview when user hits the takepic button it goes to the next activity with bitmap data. In the second activity, user can see the image view of what they just take and if they like it there is button like and once it gets pushed the pic gets saved or there is button dislike when being pushed it goes to previous activity to retake a pic.Anybody can give me a bit advice how to build that app.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier if your follow the [tutorial here.](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html)

Note that instead of passing the bitmap object to the next activity, save it to a temporary location and pass the path of the created file in the intent. If the user dislikes the image, delete the temp image and call `finish()` to go back to the picture capturing activity.